# What is the point of rewarding existing answers?

Tags: support

I'm not sure I understand the "Reward Existing Answer" bounty. Specifically, why aren't new answers eligible for the bounty? Why would someone start a bounty for an existing answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is for users who come across an answer they think is great that they want to award some of their reputation to as a bonus.  Maybe there's an answer with a lot fewer upvotes than another that you think deserves some recognition or just to encourage a poster to continue creating quality content.